# Cloudera CDP Private Cloud - Installation failed on hosts

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, cloudera, cloudera-manager, cloudera-cdp

I get an installation failed on hosts error while usng Cloudera Manager to install CDP 7.1.4 runtime on a trial basis. For this purpose I have spun up two VMs( Ubuntu 18), which use a NatNetwork to connect to each other( I can ping, and connect from one to another using ssh, also mocked a server on port 7182 on one machine, and nc connect to that port).

[image: sample output code from failure on VM]

Firewall is disabled, ports are open, TLS is disabled, but the agent still stops. What could cause this break?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to share code/errors.

Answer (score 0):

Port 7182 is just for CM server communication to agents, but We may require some other ports to be open for the management services. There are many possibilities here, however; let me provide some things to check:

-Forward/Reverse DNS lookup
-Cloudera Management Services Ports:

HMON
8091, 9994 and 9995

SMON
9996, 9997, 8086
-Dropped packages: please check if the NIC is having any issues with a simple #ifconfig
-/opt folder space. We need ~20-25 GB
-Root privileges to install the agent, We may need SSH passwordless to send the addhostscript

*This is just guessing, but We can have more insights into the STderr

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).